# Can I get the URL used from the stub class created with wsdl.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I'm working with a customer whose web service doesn't return the data in every case. Since the C# stub code is generated by calling wsdl.exe, I'm wondering how to get the actual URL used for any particular method call. I  would like to feed the URL to a browser to show them (aka point fingers).

Comment: you could fetch the Url property and then pass it to Process.Start so it shows up in a browser

Answer (score 0):

You can set the URL property on your service object? Is that what you mean?